# Sufficient condition for a set to be a group - Intuition

Tags: group-theory, intuition

From Herstein's $Topics\ in\ Algebra$ Chapter 2, we have the following problem(s):

If a set under a closed associative product (binary) has:

$(1)$ An element $e\in G$ such that $\forall a\in G$, $ae=a$;

$(2)$ $\forall a\in G$, an element $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=e$

then $G$ is a group. Further, if instead in $(2)$ we have instead that $a^{-1}a=e$, then prove, via example, that $G$ need not be a group.

$$$$I was able to prove the first part via manipulations, as follows (in short):

We have $e(a^{-1})^{-1}=aa^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=ae=a\Rightarrow e(a^{-1})^{-1}=ea\Rightarrow ea=a$.

Further, we also get from the first equality that $a^{-1}aa^{-1}=a^{-1}\Rightarrow a^{-1}a=e$

A counterexample, for the second part is a set with the product defined as $xy=x$, for $x,y\in G$.

$$$$

My question is simply - I'm looking for some intuition behind why this holds, if indeed there is any available.

Comment: Can you highlight the portion you have taken from the book?

Comment: By highlight, you mean?

Comment: I don't know if there is any seriously intuitive reason for this, but somehow it seems plausible that assuming right identity + right inverse yields a more coherent conclusion that assuming right identity + left inverse.

Comment: @taritgoswami, I'm afraid I do not have access to a digital copy